# Sending multiple CAN signals at same time QT

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, can-bus

I have been trying to send multiple CAN signals at the same time. When selecting each signal for sending, the signal is repeatedly transmitted till its cycle length and if I have to send more signals along with it, it stays in the queue. I need to run multiple signals at the same time and see their output in GUI.

Is it possible to the above function?

my code for emitting multiple signals is :

```
        foreach(QString payload_id, payload_send_final) {
            const QByteArray payload = QByteArray::fromHex(payload_id.remove(QLatin1Char(' ')).toLatin1());
            frame = QCanBusFrame(frameId, payload);
            if(m_ui->cycle_check->isChecked())
                emit sendFrame(frame,cycle_len.at(i));
            else
                emit sendFrame(frame,"1");

            i = i + 1;
        }
```

and writing Can signal is as follows :

```
    m_frame_list.enqueue(frame);
    send_frame_str = frame.toString();
    QTimer timer;
    int i = 1;

    while (!m_frame_list.isEmpty()) {
        QCanBusFrame m_frame = m_frame_list.dequeue();
        while ( i <= cycle.toInt()) {
            m_canDevice->writeFrame(frame);
            delay(5500);
            i = i+1;
        }
    }
```

And the delay function is

```
void MainWindow::delay( int millisecondsToWait )
{
    QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs( millisecondsToWait );
    while( QTime::currentTime() < dieTime )
    {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents( QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100 );
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time"? On a single bus? What is the value of `cycle` while sending? What is the delay function? If your delay functions is waiting for the given amount in ms, than your inner while loop needs `5.5 sec * cycle * queue-size`.

Comment: I meant that I want to send multiple signals to CanBus at the same time and receive a response from ocu. The cycle is the number of times the signal is sent repeatedly and is extracted from dbc file.  The delay function is a part of Qtimer. I have updated the post

Comment: Try to debug the application and see where it fails. And still, the calculation stays. Say your cycle is 10 and the queue size is 10 that's 550 sec, that's almost 10 minutes....

Comment: Actually, the signal never fails. It is running fine. The problem is that when I want to send another signal, it goes into the queue and waits for the previous signal to finish cycle number of time and then process the new signal. I want to send the new signal at the same time and get output for the signal at the same time without stopping the other signal. Is this possible?

Comment: No, you cannot sent multiple signals on a single CAN bus at the same time. You could however, change the sending behaviour though. By not trying to send a single signal cyclte-times before trying the next message, but rather by pushing the message back with with the cycle information added to the message...

Comment: I think what you want is to send several messages _in sequence_ on the same bus. That is, one at a time. Also check out how "bus arbitration" works on CAN.